# Does Hilbert's $\varepsilon$-calculus have any real problem when using for incomplete systems?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

In Mathias' paper *Hilbert, Bourbaki and the scorning of logic* (see [https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/hbslmag2.pdf](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Eardm/hbslmag2.pdf)), he mentions Hilbert's $\varepsilon$-calculus (and thus Bourbaki's $\tau$-calculus) is not suitable for incomplete systems. But he did not elaborate if there is any real problem (like inconsistency or incapability) with it.

Obviously Hilbert hoped to use $\varepsilon$-calculus to prove the completeness of systems like ZFC, and failed as we know. But this does not mean $\varepsilon$-calculus itself has any problems.

So, is  Mathias' criticism out of his personal flavor of logic and educational reasons, or there is any real problem for $\varepsilon$-calculus in incomplete systems?

Comment: Can you give a more precise citation for the relevant discussion (the paper's a bit long)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber You may read the discussion beginning at page 30.

Comment: [Crossposted from MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379266/does-hilberts-varepsilon-calculus-have-any-real-problem-when-using-for-incom).

Comment: @Noah Schweber Oh, sorry, I didn't notice they belong to the same website. Do you have any idea on Mathias' paper now?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Also, the discussion begins at page 22. The comment no.30 in the left corner on that page cheats me. :D

Comment: I think you should read the paper carefully and then come back to MSE if there any specific points that you would like to have clarified. As things stand, your question seems too vague to admit any useful answer.

Comment: @Rob Arthan I read his paper carefully more than twice. My question seems vague because Mathias' objection to $\varepsilon$-calculus is value too. Let me ask a specific question: Is Bourbaki's set theory (which is based on the equivalent $\tau$-calculus) inconsistent, or unable to prove something, comparing with ZFC in a first order system without $\tau$ operator? If so, is it because $\tau$ operator make it that way?

Comment: Also, if not, is this paper all about Mathias' personal objection of $\varepsilon$-calculus. But $\varepsilon$-calculus itself and Bourbaki's set theory have nothing wrong.

Comment: After a quick look, I don’t have much idea. The argument he invokes there rather suggests that $\epsilon$-calculus is more suitable for theories with *definable Skolem functions*, but this is quite tangential to completeness.

Comment: I think Mathias is pointing to the fact that if $\exists x\phi$ is undecidable, so is $\phi(\epsilon_x\phi)$, which implies that the denotation of the term $\epsilon_x\phi$ in the intended interpretation has not much to do with $\phi$. I have mentioned the model-theoretic problem that I think is the most serious in this related question:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346225/why-bourbakis-epsilon-calculus-is-not-suitable-for-set-theory?rq=1

Comment: @Rodrigo Freire But $\phi$ means $\phi(x)$, where $x$ is a single letter, and thus is not the same as $\phi(\varepsilon_x\phi)$. For model-theoretic problem, it is true that Bourbaki's system is hard to do model theory on it. But I don't think that means Bourbaki's system itself has any "logic errors".

Comment: The logical part of Bourbaki's system is a conservative extension of first-order logic, so it does not have any "logical mistakes" in this sense. Of course, $\phi(x)$ is different from $\phi(\epsilon_x\phi)$, I was just interpreting Mathias (page 23): $\epsilon_x\phi$ is supposed to be closely related to $\phi$ (a "function of $\phi$), but if $\exists x\phi$ is undecidable, then $\epsilon_x\phi$ may be considered to be vaguely related to $\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert on this subject, and it has been many years since I've read Bourbaki's Theory of Sets and do not have a copy available to me, but I'll point out a couple of things I see in this paper.

First, at least some of his argument appears to be valid. Bourbaki's formalism does lead to some very misleading statements. As an informal conception, in Bourbaki's theory somebody has listed out every possible relation $R_x$, and chosen, once-for-all-time, an object for each - if possible one that if substituted for $x$ would make $R_x$ true. This selected item is written as $\tau_x(R_x)$. In the actual theory, they are just formal symbols and the interpretation is supported by the chosen axioms. So $\tau_x(x = 1) = 1$ while $\tau_x(x \ne x)$ could be anything at all. But the key thing is, it is still some object that can be considered. In particular, for any $R_x$, you can prove
$$(\exists b)(b = \tau_x(R_x))$$
even when $(\exists x)R_x$ is false. ($(\exists x)R_x$ is short-hand for $R_x(\tau_x(R_x(x))$.)

This becomes a problem when combined with the set builder notation: $$\{x\mid R_x\} := \tau_y((\forall x)(x \in y \iff R_x))$$
Therefore, while the statement $$(\exists y)(\forall x)(x \in y \iff x \notin x)$$ is provably false in Bourbaki's formalism, the statement
$$(\exists b)(b = \{x\mid x\notin x\})$$
is provably true. It just means something different that we expect it to mean. The natural, even intended, interpretation of $(\exists b)(b = \{ x\mid x\notin x\})$ is that there is a set consisting of every set that is not an element of itself. But in Bourbaki's theory, $\{ x\mid x \notin x\}$ exists but is an object with no connection to the relation $x \notin x$.

Thus Bourbaki is consistent here (as far as I can see), but does it by subtly changing the meaning of the notation from what we expect.

---

On the other hand, some of his criticism appears to me to be unfair. For example from page 22:

> B-13 Thus there is an acute difference between the normal use, in $\bf ZF$ and many other set theories, of the class-forming operator $\{\ \mid\ \}$ with the Church conversion schema $x \in \{x\mid R\}\iff R$ holding for all classes whether sets or not, and the Bourbaki treatment whereby, magically, conversion holds for a class if and only if that class is a set.

where he apparently fails to understand that in Bourbaki's theory, there is no such thing as a "proper class". The only objects are sets, so "conversion holds for a class if and only if that class is a set" makes no sense, as the only interpretation possible for the word "class" is "set".

Now of course one may prefer to have a theory that allows classes. But the failure to include classes in this theory is not a problem with the theory itself, only in our expectations. To pretend that the theory is mishandling a concept when in fact that concept does not appear in it is disingenuous.

Comment: But in Bourbaki's book(at least the 1970 version), the abbreviation $\{x|R_x \}$ is used only if $R_x$ is "collectivizing", which means $(\exists y)(\forall x)((x\in y)\Leftrightarrow R_x)$ is true. So such an set is guaranteed to exist. Also, Bourbaki proved $x\notin x$ is not collectivizing in his set theory.

Comment: Also, I agree with you understanding that there is no proper class in Bourbaki's set theory. Actually there is no proper class in ZF too. When we consider proper classes of ZF, we actually stand on the extension theory of ZF.

Comment: @zqfmath - note the part at the start about not having read the book in years, and not have a copy available for reference. I in fact pointed out that under Boubaki, $x \notin x$ is not collectivizing - except as the fully stated result $\lnot(\exists y)(\forall x)(x \in y \iff x \notin x)$. So Bourbaki mitigates the problem by restricting set builder notation to when it makes sense. But that is only window-dressing. The underlying issue is still there. Its meanings are subtly different from the expected. Not an issue with the theory in itself, but it disagrees with common concepts.